# Spring MVC Encode non-English parameters

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I use spring MVC to get parameter by @PathVariable as follow:

```
@GetMapping("/users/{username}")
public Boolean getUser(@PathVariable("username") String username)
{
     // do some works
}
```

when my input paramater is none english(such as arabic), I could not get correct value of parameter and username parameter contain invalid ASCII code. in addition, I am sure that the client send request url in UTF-8 format.

I test spring character encoding filter to solve but it, but it is not work.

```
<filter>  
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>  
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>  
    <init-param>  
       <param-name>encoding</param-name>  
       <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>  
    </init-param>  
    <init-param>  
       <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>  
       <param-value>true</param-value>  
    </init-param>  
</filter>  
<filter-mapping>  
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>  
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>  
</filter-mapping>
```

I test my code with @RequestsParam and HttpServletRequest, but all of them return invalid characters, also, I used URLEncoder.encode and URLDecoder.decode but could solve problem.

Comment: Show your DispatcherServler mapping?

Comment: <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve my problem by using ISO_8859_1 char set by using this code:

```
username = new String(username.getBytes(CharSets.ISO_8859_1));
```

but, really I don't know what is reason ? I expect to use UTF-8 encoding to get correct value of parameter, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Totally, by using post method this problem will be solved

Answer (score 0):

When request use GET method,encodingFilter is invalid.You should configure application server's URIEncoding.eg:Modify Tomcat's server.xml,add URIEncoding.

`<Connector URIEncoding="UTF-8" port="80" protocol="HTTP/1.1" connectionTimeout="20000" redirectPort="8443" />`

Comment: But I need to solve this bug without depending on special web server, application should be independent from web server and work with any server such as Tomcat, Jboss(WildFly), WebLogic and so on.

Comment: Usually i  choose POST method and encodingFilter to avoid this problem